# GPO with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, gpo

I would like to enable or disable a windows native GPO, how do I?

I'm trying to use:

Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy Objects{0E01D989-87F3-42F2-969F-F88F33C1AFBB}Machine\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU" -Name NoAutoUpdate -Value 1

I noticed that this part of the registry "{0E01D989-87F3-42F2-969F-F88F33C1AFBB}Machine" changes when restarting the computer or when opening and closing the registry, so I can't reuse this one script where it contains this registry because it always is changed.

Is there a way to dynamically allocate this registry value? Is there another way to manipulate GPO to just enable or disable?

Comment: do you want to disable local computer policy or Group policy applied to your machine/user ?

Comment: In fact, the aim is to create a script that makes the necessary changes to all group policies on all machines in the company.

Comment: I used Set-ItemProperty because I noticed that when enabling a group policy manually in gpedit the registry is changed, what I did was use this command to change the part of the registry I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

> I noticed that this part of the registry
> `"{0E01D989-87F3-42F2-969F-F88F33C1AFBB}Machine"` changes when
> restarting the computer or when opening and closing the registry.

You could *compute* a variable part of registry key(s), e.g. as follows:

```
$PathBase = "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy Objects"
$PathTail = "Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU"
Get-ChildItem -Path $PathBase |
  Where-Object { $_.Name -match "Machine$" } |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty PSChildName |
      ForEach-Object {
        $PathPart = Join-Path -Path $PathBase -ChildPath $_
        $PathReal = Join-Path -Path $PathPart -ChildPath $PathTail
        if ( Test-Path $PathReal -PathType Container ) {
            ###              ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
            Set-ItemProperty -WhatIf -Path $PathReal -Name NoAutoUpdate -Value 1
            ###              ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
        }
      }
```

Note the [`-WhatIf` switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-7.2#-whatif) (do not remove until debugged):

> ### -WhatIf
>
> Displays a message that describes the effect of the command, instead
> of executing the command.